# SVG sanitization in Angular 7

Tags: angular, svg

I'm trying to sanitize an `SVG` object without any luck.

I have the following HTML template:

**canvas.component.html**

```
<object #worldMap class="worldMap" [attr.data]="'assets/canvas/world.svg' | safe: 'resourceUrl'" type="image/svg+xml" id="worldMap">Your browser doesn't support SVG</object>
```

and in **safe.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeStyle, SafeScript, SafeUrl, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safe'
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {    
  constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  public transform(value: any, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
    switch (type) {
      case 'html': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
      case 'style': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
      case 'script': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
      case 'url': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
      case 'resourceUrl': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
      default: throw new Error(`Invalid safe type specified: ${type}`);
    }
  }    
}
```

However, it doesn't work as it shows only the message inside the object tags.

What would be an alternative method to display the `SVG` from the assets folder?

Comment: This page contains useful samples: https://www.chrisjmendez.com/2017/06/17/angular-dynamically-inserting-svg-into-an-element/